# Unload statement

Tags: sql, linux, informix

I am new to programming and I am running into a issue. I am calling a table and need to put my results into a csv file in a certain path.

This is what I am doing and the error I get.

```
dbuser@cbos1:/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/testing/Abe_Lincoln> cd dbaccess labor32<<?
> UNLOAD TO '/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Cronos_test/Position7'
> select * from informix.position;
> ?
-bash: cd: dbaccess: No such file or directory
dbuser@cbos1:/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/testing/Abe_Lincoln>
```

the file path exist but keeps getting message.

Comment: `cd` is the command used to change directories, but you seem to be trying to input SQL statements to it. Is `labor32` a program? Do you have an example of any command that successfully does anything with sql?

Comment: @thatotherguy: You're right that the `cd` is unwanted.  `dbaccess` is the program; `labor32` is the name of a database.  The invocation should be just `dbaccess labor32 <<?` (no `cd`) and the following text in the here document.

Answer (score 3):

Using just `$` as the command line prompt, you should be using just:

```
$ dbaccess labor32 <<?
> UNLOAD TO '/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Cronos_test/Position7'
> select * from informix.position;
> ?

…message(s) from dbaccess

$
```

This will run the `dbaccess` program (usually from `$INFORMIXDIR/bin`) against the database `labor32`, and generate an UNLOAD format file in the given file name.

The `cd` command is for changing directory; you don't have a directory called `dbaccess` (and probably shouldn't), and even if you did have such a directory, you shouldn't provide more options to the `cd` command, or a here document as standard input — it will ignore them.

Note that the file generated (`Position7` will be the base name of the file) will be in Informix's UNLOAD format (pipe delimited fields by default), not CSV.  It's certainly possible to convert between the two; I have Perl scripts that can do the conversions — last modified about a decade ago, but not much has changed in the interim.  You could also consider using SQLCMD (available as open source from the [IIUG Software Repository](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)) which *does* have support for CSV load and unload formats.  (This is the original SQLCMD — or at least an original SQLCMD — and is not Microsoft's Johnny-come-lately program of the same name.)

---

Create a file `unload-table.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

dbaccess labor32 <<EOF
UNLOAD TO '/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Cronos_test/Position7'
SELECT * FROM informix.position;
EOF
```

You can then run this as `bash unload-table.sh`, or make it executable and install it in your `$HOME/bin` directory (which is on your PATH, isn't it?) so that you can simply run `unload-table.sh`.  Or you can arrange to 'compile' (copy) the file to `unload-table` (no `.sh` suffix) so you don't have to type it to execute it: `unload-table`.  You can enhance the script to allow the program (`dbacess`), database (`labor32`), table (`informix.position`) and file (`/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_sites/Cronos_test/Position7`) to be set as command line arguments or via environment variables.  That requires a bit of fiddling in the script, but nothing outrageous.  I'd probably allow the file name to be specified separately from the directory where the file is to be stored so that it is easier to configure on the command line.

Comment: @thatotherguy your correct about the labor32 being the database.So that works without the cd perfectly thanks on that. Now to the second part of it.........how do I get the script to run in sh (shell script). Since shell is looking for keywords to run a process.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  The shell is looking for commands to process; dbaccess is a command.  Put the commands (without the 'prompt') into a file, then run it: `bash unload-table.sh` or equivalent.  It is routine shell scripting.  You may end up wanting to make the database name, the table name, the file name configurable from the command line, but that's another bag'o'worms (more routine shell scripting, that's all).

Comment: if I try this in my bash script nothing happens. if i type in manually it does its job.                                                                  #!/bin/bash

cd /var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/testing/Abe_Lincoln

dbaccess labor32<<?
Unload To '/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Cronos_test/Position7am/Positiontest'
select * from informix.position;
?

Comment: Please include the code in an update/addendum to the question.  I can't read your code in a comment; it can't be formatted in a comment.  Is `/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Cronos_test/Position7am/Positiontest` a file or a directory?  If it is a directory, you're doomed; you need to specify a file name.  If it doesn't exist yet, is `/var/lib/dbspace/bosarc/Active_Sites/Cronos_test/Position7am/` a directory that exists?  If not, you're doomed; `dbaccess` won't create the directory.  Is the `cd` on a separate line from the `dbaccess`?

Comment: cd is the first line, 2nd line dbaccess, 3rd line unload, 4th line select, 5th line commitng informix

Comment: Pay attention to what I said.  _Please include the code in an update/addendum to the question._  Your comments describe what you think you've got; you haven't shown us what you've actually got.  Since what you think you've got should work but what you've actually got doesn't, we need to see the actual to spot the discrepancy.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was able to get the command to work. i appreciate it.